# Possibility of replicating second level cache in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

Is it possible to replicate hibernate's second level cache on different nodes in clustered environment?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the following thread *hibernate distributed 2nd level cache options*: [hibernate distributed 2nd level cache options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928013/hibernate-distributed-2nd-level-cache-options)

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do it with Infinispan, which is one of the second-level cache providers available for Hibernate, which supports distributed state management out of the box. A standalone Hibernate+Infinispan example to cluster the cache can be found [here](https://github.com/galderz/secondlc/blob/master/src/test/java/secondlc/Cluster2lcTest.java).